# Create a new function from an existing function in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pg-dump

I have created a function `function_1()` in Postgres.
Now I want to create another similar function `function_2()` and copy the content of `function_1()`.

Any Postgres command line can do that?

So far I only used copy&paste method in the command line to create `function_2()` (need to change the function name to "function_2" after paste)

Comment: i wanted to make a short hand alias for an internal function and used :
`select pg_get_functiondef ( 'current_database'::regproc )  ;`
... did a bit editing and then used :
 `create function _db ()
returns name
as
$$current_database$$
language
internal stable
parallel safe strict ;`
... for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the GUI [**pgAdmin**](http://pgadmin.org/), you can simply select the function in the object browser and open the reverse engineered SQL script in an *SQL editor* window.

There is a dedicated item in the options to automate it:

Options - Query tool - Query Editor - **Copy SQL from main window to query tool**

Answer (score 3):

`pg_dump` the function definition, or use the `pg_get_functiondef` function to get the function definition. Modifying it is up to you.

If you're trying to programmatically create functions you might be better off with PL/PgSQL's `EXECUTE` command and the `format` function to create dynamic functions.

It's pretty unusual to need to do this, suggesting you're probably doing something that's much more easily done another way.